# About definition of 'converge almost surely'

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence

I have seen two different definitions about 'converge almost surely'.

Definition 1.
The sequence of random variables $\{X_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is said to converge almost surely to the random variable X, if:

for: $\forall \epsilon > 0:\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|X_{n}-X|>\epsilon)=0$

Definition 2.
The sequence of function, $\{f_{n}(x)\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is said to converge almost surely to the function f(x), if:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(x) = f(x)$ is satisfied almost everywhere.

Are these two definitions equivalent? Let me give an example:

For each positive integer k, define k indicator functions on the interval [0,1):

$f_{i}^{(k)}(x) = 1$, for x $\in[\frac{i-1}{k},\frac{i}{k})$; and $f_{i}^{(k)}(x) = 0$, otherwise. For each k, let i = 1, 2, ... k, respectively.

Put these indicator functions in a sequence that:

$\varphi_{1}(x)=f_{1}^{1}(x)$, $\varphi_{2}(x)=f_{1}^{2}(x)$, $\varphi_{3}(x)=f_{2}^{2}(x)$, $\varphi_{4}(x)=f_{1}^{3}(x)$, $\varphi_{5}(x)=f_{2}^{3}(x)$, ...

It can be simply prove that $\{\varphi_{n}(x)\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ does not converge almost surely to 0, by definition 2.

However, by definition 1, the limit: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\varphi_{n}(x)|$ does not exist, because for any $x_{0}$ $\in$ [0,1), there will be infinitely many zeros and ones in the sequence of $\{\varphi_{n}(x_{0})\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$.

Therefore, $\mathbb{P}(\{x:\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\})$ = 0, and hence the sequence converges almost surely to 0, by definition 1.

What was wrong?

Comment: Definition 1 is sweeping too much under the carpet.  If the limit doesn't exist for a nonnull set, then it doesn't make any sense to talk about the probability of the set $\lim\lvert X_n-X\rvert>\epsilon$ (which requires the measurable function $\lim\lvert X_n-X\rvert\colon\Omega\to[-\infty,+\infty]$ to exist and is defined as the event $(\lim\lvert X_n-X\rvert)^{-1}((\epsilon,+\infty])$) and hence "something which doesn't exist is equal to 0" is of course false.

Comment: Where did you see Definition 1?

Comment: I saw Definition 1 on the lecture notes of one of my undergraduate courses.

Comment: If you replace $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ by $\lim \sup_{n\to \infty}$ in Defintion 1 then it makes sense and it is also equivalent to Definition 2.

Comment: As @KaviRamaMurthy said, the problem is nicely fixed up if you use $\limsup$. The actual operator $\lim$ is really rather awkward in analysis because using it implicitly implies that the limit exists, and so the negation of a statement using $\lim$ can't actually be written using $\lim$ (short of just putting $\neg$ at the front and leaving it there).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy : If your comments answer the question, you should post them as such.  In general, questions should not be answered in comments.